# Emacs CC-Mode Tab Indent

Tags: emacs

Is there a way that will allow languages within CC-Mode (e.g., C, Java,...) to auto-indent with TAB and allow me to insert a literal TAB character (\t) by pressing TAB?

I could try to use `Ctrl-q TAB` but it simply inserts spaces within CC-Mode.

I've tried some of the indent commands from the CC-Mode indent manual though those haven't worked nor did some seem to match what I was trying to achieve.